# Restricting subclasses from inheriting certain methods of base class

Tags: c#, overriding, class-design

```
using System;

public class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
    }

    public void M1()
    {
    }

    public void M2()
    {
    }

    public void M3()
    {
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    //this class should get only method 1
}

public class SecondDerived : Base
{
    //this class should get only method 2 and method3
}
```

The requirement is : the base class contains the 3 methods `M1`, `M2`, `M3`.
The derived class should inherit only `M1` and SecondDerived should inherit only `M2` and `M3`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Explain more about *why* the requirement is that way. Simply put, it specifically can't be done. But with more information, we might be able to provide a workable solution.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Not knowing is worth donwvotes in SO now? The question is well formulated and clear, not knowing is not a sin...jesus

Comment: Even if there were a way to prevent Derived from inheriting `Derived.M1`, it could just cast `this` to `Base`, and then call `Base.M1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do what you want with inheritance.

It seems you have no intention of overriding, you simply want to "inherit" behavior from the base class selectively. You could do this using a "has a" relationship:

```
public class Base
{
     internal Base() {} //mark constructor as internal so it can not be used outside your assembly if necessary

     public Foo Mehtod1() {...}
     public Foo Mehtod2() {...}
     public Foo Mehtod3() {...}
}
```

Then simply do the following:

```
class A
{
     private Base internalBase;

     public A() { this.internalBase = new Base(); }

     public Foo Method1() { return this.internalBase.Method1(); }
}

class B
{
     private Base internalBase;

     public A() { this.internalBase = new Base(); }

     public Foo Method2() { return this.internalBase.Method2(); }
     public Foo Method3() { return this.internalBase.Method3(); }
}
```

**UPDATE:** A possible alternative solution is to make your `Base` class methods `virtual` and override them all in your derived classes, throwing `NotSupportedException`s in those methods that you do not want the class to make available. I don't really like this solution but it has the advantage of not loosing the polyphormism inheritance gives you which might be useful if you have some core base functionality which all derived classes will share (in your example you seem to imply they wont).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot selectively inherit methods like this. A derived class automatically inherits all public methods of the base class. I suggest you to split the `Base` class into two classes:

```
public class Base1
{
    public Base1()
    {
    }

    public void M1()
    {
    }
}

public class Base2
{
    public void M2()
    {        
    }

    public void M3()
    {       
    }
}

public class First : Base1

public class Second : Base2
```

Comment: Not sure I like this solution. What happens if M1, M2 and M3 share state information or core implementation? I'd just go for a "has a" relationship in this scenario and keep the Base class as it is.

Comment: @InBetween: I agree with your concern, but in the absence of further clarifications I can only propose something for what he specified.

Comment: :) Just nittpicking and thinking in a broader and unspecified scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it in this way. Inheritance implies an "IS A" relationship.

If `SecondDerived` would not have a `M1()` then it would not be compatible with a reference to a the `class Base`.

So maybe you shouldn't be using inheritance for whatever problem you're solving.

Comment: +1 for "... would not be compatible with a [base class] reference". On the other hand, I've seen the "not implementedException", as suggested by @InBetween, used with interfaces (hint, hint).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by adding Obsolete attribute

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void M1() { }
    public void M2() { }
    public void M3() { }
}

public class B : A
{
    [Obsolete("You can not use this", true)]
    public sealed override void M1()
    {

    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public void Test()
    {
        // Will show error 
        base.M1();

    }
}
```